# дергание анимации, когда заканчивается минута

Tags: javascript, css-animation

С помощью setInterval делаю анимацию стрелок часов, но каждую минуту анимация дергается. Т.е. доходит до 60 и происходит дерганье. Можно ли это убрать в текущей реализации ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS + CSS Clock</title>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="clock">
    <div class="clock-face">
      <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <style>
    html {
      font-family:'helvetica neue';
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    body {
      font-size: 2rem;
      display:flex;
      flex:1;
      min-height: 100vh;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .clock {
      width: 30rem;
      height: 30rem;
      border:20px solid white;
      border-radius:50%;
      margin:50px auto;
      position: relative;
      padding:2rem;
      box-shadow:
      0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
      inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF,
      inset 0 0 10px black,
      0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .clock-face {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transform: translateY(-3px); /* account for the height of the clock hands */
    }

    .hand {
      width:50%;
      height:6px;
      background:black;
      position: absolute;
      top:50%;
      transform-origin: 100%;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transition: all 0.05s;
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
    }

  </style>

  <script>
    const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
    const minsHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
    const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

    function setDate() {
      const now = new Date();
      const seconds = now.getSeconds();
      const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
      secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;

      const mins = now.getMinutes();
      const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + 90;
      minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;

      const hour = now.getHours();
      const hourDegrees = ((hour / 12) * 360) + 90;
      hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;
    }

    setInterval(setDate, 1000);
    setDate();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вынесите получение текущего времени и его отображение в разные функции. Это позволит отлаживать анимацию покадрово.

Comment: И, пожалуйста, уберите все лишнее из вашего кода. Я почему-то сомневаюсь что фоновая картинка как-то влияет на этот баг.

Comment: Кстати, небольшая поправка. Обычно минутная и часовая стрелки перемещаются не каждую минуту/час, а каждую секунду.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вот здесь, я завалился: Это позволит отлаживать анимацию покадрово

Comment: в смысле - завалился?

Comment: не понимаю что это значит, отлаживать покадрово, это в инспекторе браузера я так понимаю, можно пример?

Comment: *"Вынесите получение текущего времени и его отображение в разные функции."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данное дерганье вызывает плавная анимация в CSS стилях, которая охватывает полностью всё. Поэтому, когда вы делали резкий поворот, он делался "плавно" и выглядел как дёрганье

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
const minsHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;

  const mins = now.getMinutes();
  const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + 90;
  minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;

  const hour = now.getHours();
  const hourDegrees = ((hour / 12) * 360) + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
setDate();
```

```css
html {
  font-family:'helvetica neue';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.clock {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border:20px solid white;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:50px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding:2rem;
  box-shadow:
  0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
  inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF,
  inset 0 0 10px black,
  0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.clock-face {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.hand {
  width:50%;
  height:6px;
  background:black;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  /*transition: all 0.05s;*/
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
    <div class="clock-face">
      <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю всего, но если `js` не обязателен, то проще сделать на `css` -

```css
.clock {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.clock__second-hand {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  position: relative;
  
  animation: r 120s steps(120) infinite;
}

.clock__second-hand:before {
  content: "";
  
  width: 1px;
  height: 50px;
  
  background: #c3c3c3;
  
  display: block;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
}

@keyframes r {
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="clock__second-hand"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что проиходит резкая смена градусов поворота при измении секунд с 59 на 0. Поэтому виден такой скачок. Решается просто заменой

```
const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
```

на

```
let secondsDegrees = 0;
  if (seconds < 45) {
     secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  }else {
    secondsDegrees = (((seconds - 60) / 60) * 360) + 90;
  }
```

Точно так же нужно изменить минуты и часы.
Найти это было не сложно. Требовалось вынести создание даты из функции, а измение даты сделать принудительным, тогда легко поставить точку останова в инструментах разработчика и дебажить посекундно без привязки к реальному времени

```
.....
const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');
const now = new Date();

function setDate() {
  now.setTime(now.getTime() + 1000);
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
....
```

Comment: Так тоже можно :) +1